# star.cutoffs include only p<0.05 and p<0.01

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

In the default setting, "stargazer" shows three star cutoffs (*p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01), but I want to only include two cutoffs, **p<0.05; ***p<0.01.

When I put,

```
star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01)
```

I get the result as:

```
 *p<0.05; **p<0.01; ***p<[0.***]
```

Two issues here:
 1. ***p<[0.***] is shown (I only want to show two cutoffs (0.05 and 0.01)
 2. one star (*) is allocated to p<0.05 instead of two, and two starts for p<0.01 instead of three

Comment: I found how to do this. Below is how I did.

star.char = c("**", "***"),
 star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01),
          notes.append = FALSE,
          notes = "**p<0.05; ***p<0.01",

Comment: I tried this but could not get it to work.

Comment: Correction. I was able to get it to work. Good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the star cutoffs in stargazer is confusing because there are actually three or four different options that need to be adjusted.

- **star.cutoffs**: As the stargazer manual notes: "For elements with NA values, the corresponding 'star' will not be used." So, for the code above, it might be better to use `star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, NA)`. This may result, however, in the Notes row at the bottom of the table now saying `NA`.
- **notes.append**: Now set `notes.append = FALSE`
- **notes**: Finally, set `notes` = to your preferred legend, in this case `notes = "*$p<0.05$; **$p<0.01$"`
- **star.char**: If you wanted to use some other symbol other than stars, you would need to pass an argument to `star.char` but not in this example.

See sample code below:

```
## for two cutoffs
stargazer(...,
    star.cutoffs = c(.05, .01, NA),
    #star.char    = c("*", "**", ""),          # not necessary for this example
    notes.append     = FALSE,
    notes            = "*$p<0.05$; **$p<0.01$" # $$ = math mode for latex
  )

## for one cutoff
stargazer(...,
    star.cutoffs = c(.05, NA, NA),
    #star.char    = c("*", NA, NA),   # not necessary for this example
    notes.append     = FALSE,
    notes            = "*$p<0.05$".   # $$ = math mode for latex
  )
```